# Leer un Array de otra función en Android Studio

Tags: android, variables

```
public class Productos extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView lstDatos;
private Adaptador adaptador;

//test
TextView textView;

String IP = "http://xxxxxxx";
String GET = IP + "/productos.php";

ObtenerWebService hiloconexion;
public String[][] productos = new String[10][10];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista);

    //textview test para checkear algun resultado
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    hiloconexion = new ObtenerWebService();
    hiloconexion.execute(GET, "1");


    lstDatos = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstDatos);
    adaptador = new Adaptador(this, GetArrayItems() );
    lstDatos.setAdapter(adaptador);

}


public class ObtenerWebService extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[][]> {

    @Override
    protected String[][] doInBackground(String... params) {

        String cadena = params[0];
        URL url = null; // Url de donde queremos obtener información

        if(params[1]=="1"){

            try {
                url = new URL(cadena);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); //Abrir la conexión
                connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0" +
                        " (Linux; Android 1.5; es-ES) Ejemplo HTTP");

                int respuesta = connection.getResponseCode();
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

                if (respuesta == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){

                    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());  // preparo la cadena de entrada
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));  // la introduzco en un BufferedReader

                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);        // Paso toda la entrada al StringBuilder
                    }

                    JSONObject respuestaJSON = new JSONObject(result.toString());
                    String resultJSON = respuestaJSON.getString("estado");

                    if (resultJSON=="1"){     
                        JSONArray infoJSON = respuestaJSON.getJSONArray("productos");   // estado es el nombre del campo en el JSON
                        for(int i=0;i<infoJSON.length();i++){
                            productos[i][1] = infoJSON.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
                            productos[i][2] = infoJSON.getJSONObject(i).getString("nombre");
                            productos[i][3] = infoJSON.getJSONObject(i).getString("foto");

                        }
```

// EN ESTE PUNTO HE COMPROBADO QUE EL ARRAY CONTIENE TODOS LOS ELEMENTOS CORRECTAMENTE, EJ: productos[2][2] contiene "Nombre equipo".

```
                    }
                    else if (resultJSON=="2"){
                        //devuelve = "Error #1";
                    }


                }


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
        return productos;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled(String s[][]) {
        super.onCancelled(s);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s[][]) {
        productos = s;  //AQUI QUIERO PASAR EL ARRAY s al ARRAY productos para tratarlo en la ultima funcion.
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }


}

private ArrayList<Entidad> GetArrayItems() {
    ArrayList<Entidad> listItems = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int p=0; p<productos.length; p++){
        listItems.add(new Entidad(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, ""+productos[p][2], "Descripcion test."));
    }
    //listItems.add(new Entidad(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Nombre Equipo 1", "Descripcion test."));

    return listItems;
}
```

}

Edito: He agregado el código completo y reformulo la pregunta.
El array producto guarda correctamente la información, lo he comprobado, pero en alguna parte ese array se inicializa y no consigo poner enviarlo a la función que crea el arraylist.

¿Alguna opinión? Por circunstancias laborales estoy tratando de aprender android a la carrera, tengan paciencia.. :(

Comment: ¿Cómo lo estás leyendo?  ¿Qué error te está dando?  ¿No será que el código se queda por allá: `hiloconexion.execute();` y no vuelve?

Comment: Energy Panel, bienvenido!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, es muy importante leer [ask], saludos!

Comment: Revisa los enlaces que te sugiero @EnergyPanel en cuanto a tu pregutna agrega la clase completa, donde defines el array, a nivel de clase o dentro de un método?, donde esta onCreate() ?

Comment: He actualizado en el primer mensaje todo el código y reformulo la pregunta.

Comment: @EnergyPanel gracias por modificar tu pregunta!. Con respecto a "Por circunstancias laborales estoy tratando de aprender android a la carrera, tengan paciencia", aquí es el sitio adecuado para obtener información si es que se realizan correctamente las preguntas, y tenemos mucha paciencia! :)

Comment: @EnergyPanel te refieres a que al llamar GetArrayItems() no se lee valor del array productos? se podría ver la url o un ejemplo de que estructura genera?

Comment: Lo estás inicializando tú mismo al hacer esto: `protected void onPostExecute(String s[][]) {
        productos = s;  //AQUI QUIERO PASAR EL ARRAY s al ARRAY productos para tratarlo en la ultima funcion.
    }`... lo que debes hacer es pasar la variable al método que quieras: **`protected void onPostExecute(String s[][]) {
        tuMetodo(s);
    }`** [Revisa el ejemplo de la documentación](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). La variable que `onPostExecute` recibe como parámetro es la respuesta misma, no tienes que igualarla a nada.

Comment: @A.Cedano entiendo, tendría que dejar algo como esto: 

protected void onPostExecute(String s[][]) {
            adaptador = new Adaptador(this, GetArrayItems(s) );
            lstDatos.setAdapter(adaptador);
        }

Pero me salta el error de "cannot be applied"

Comment: El problema es que tu código está algo confuso... este método `ArrayList<Entidad> GetArrayItems` debería recibir un `ArrayList` del tipo `Entidad`, pero tú no indicas en ninguna parte que `s`  sea un `ArrayList` de ese tipo. Primeramente, prueba si `s` se está recibiendo bien en el `onPostExecute` y luego procede a normalizar los datos que guardas, indicando que los mismos son del tipo adecuado, **no en el método, sino cuando obtienes los datos del servidor**.

Comment: @EnergyPanel agregué una respuesta, en realidad son dos detalles que noto, el primero es que el AsyncTask puede obtener los datos hasta tiempo después de que llamas el método GetArrayItems() y el segundo es que cuando revisas el valor de "estado" dentro del JSON lo estas realizando incorrectamente por lo tanto los valores en el array productos no se estarían llenando, dejo como resolver ambos problemas.

Comment: @Jorgesys te confirmo que los valores del array si se rellenan porque justo al salir del if en en la misma funcion hago un textView.setText(productos[2][2]); y el textview lo carga.

Comment: @A.Cedano la cosa es que el codigo lo he ido plasmando desde un tutorial en youtube que en vez de usar array usaba un string y asi si me funcionaba, pero al meter arrays pues no... seguiré investigando. Yo también lo veo confuso :S

Comment: @realiza los cambios que comento y prueba nuevamente.

Comment: Para hacer el código menos confuso, tú puedes armar tu objeto directamente donde tratas la respuesta del servidor, y luego pasas ese objeto al método que sea, para mostrar su contenido. En el código yo veo que primero tú haces un tratamiento bastante confuso de la respuesta (en el `doInBackground`), y luego intentas pasar los datos obtenidos  al método `GetArrayItems` para luego hacer `return` ¿?.  Deberías crear tu objeto válido en el `doInBackground` y luego en el `onPostExecute` pasarlo a un método para leer esos datos, no para volver a meterlos en otro array. No sé si me explico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeramente, recuerda que la ejecución del `Asynctask` es como su nombre lo indica "Asincronica" por lo tanto estarías llamando el método  `GetArrayItems()` cuando posiblemente aún no termina el `Asynctask` su tarea.

Para asegurar que termine la obtención de resultados usa el método [.get()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get()) de esta forma primero obtendría los resultados.

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista);

            //textview test para checkear algun resultado
            textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

            hiloconexion = new ObtenerWebService();
            try {
                hiloconexion.execute(GET, "1").get(); //* Usa el metodo get()!
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            lstDatos = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstDatos);
            adaptador = new Adaptador(this, GetArrayItems() );
            lstDatos.setAdapter(adaptador);
            ...
            ...
```

Segundo la comparación de Strings se realiza mediante el método .equals() por lo tanto debes cambiar estas comparaciones.

```
   ...
   ...
   String resultJSON = respuestaJSON.getString("estado");

   //if (resultJSON=="1"){ //* INCORRECTO.
   if (resultJSON.equals("1")){ //* CORRECTO
   ...
   ...
   else if (resultJSON.equals("2")){ //*CORRECTO
   ...
```

---

No olvides declarar el permiso para Internet en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Que crack! Con tu correción me he enterado mejor de como funcionan el Asynctask y además está mucho más claro. También me he apuntado la forma de usar los if.

Y ya me funciona, gracias de nuevo!

Comment: @EnergyPanel recuerde aceptar la respuesta si solucionó su problema.

Comment: @EnergyPanel excelente! recuerda que este es el sitio donde puedes encontrar información ! , no olvides realizar el [tour] y leer [ask] y [asnwer] cuando contribuyas!, saludos!